# JOOMLA error message JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

During testing on my Joomla (3.4.1) site, I saw a system error message when I tried to access the login page or registration page if I'm already logged in.
The question is: where can I change this behaviour in the code? I would like to do a redirect instead of showing this message.

Thanks

Comment: Then, when logged in, the **registration** and **login** pages are juste showing the text key "JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR" ?

Comment: @Michel yes when i try to access to registration page or login and im already logged in, im redirected to home with that text key.

Comment: Have you checked the authorizations of this user and theses pages ? Are you using some extension that could have an influence on this ?

Comment: @Michel How can i check authtorization? In using standard com_users for login and registration

Answer (score 0):

log in to your Joomla website back-end as administrator. Go to Menus and then to Menu Items and select the menu that your Login Form is in that. In the list of this menu items click on the name of your login form. You will be moved to the page Menus: Edit Item. In the tabs in this page click on Options tab. Here change the values of the *Menu Item Login Redirect* and *Menu Item Logout Redirect* from default to any page you want the user be redirected to (for example Home). Finally click Save & Close button and test it.